# UIAlertView showing after refresh view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertview

I Have this code:

```
    else if ([response isEqualToString: @"1"])
     {

        UIAlertView *alertView1 = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"FAILED" message:@"Please,  Try Again" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
         [alertView1 show];
     }
```

I catch from a JSON response an error and show this alert.
This code is into a post method of a ViewController with table view, and this view controller is a parent to another view controller. The problem is that AlertView not showing (or showing fast) in the present view (the title in navigation bar become dark), but if I going back to the parent view controller and return to this view (practically, if i "refresh" the view), the alert show correctly.

I have the same code for iPad and iPhone, but in iPad not done.

Comment: is this code called from UI/main thread?

Comment: Maybe try letting the alertView.layer.zPosition = 100; See if that helps? Although this is more of a hack than a solution.

Comment: meanwhile, thanks! yes it's called from main thread, Vinzzz. Zhang, i try to hack but nothing. The alert view, practically, appear and disappear instantly and remain in execution, then after refresh the view (go back and return) appear correctly.

Comment: Can you put a breakpoint in [alertView1 show]; & check it hits

Comment: @BC_Dilum  if i insert a breakpoint hack the problem, the alert view appear and remain in execution until, normally, press the destructive button. what's up?

Comment: @user3818207 try to go STEP OVER after the breakpoint. It may be because after the [alertView1 show]; there'll be another subview add to the SuperView.

Comment: then the strange behavior in Ipad not done, only in iphone, all type of iphone.

Comment: @BC_Dilum  there aren't another subview, there is a subview before this one, but it's dismiss with dismiss method

Comment: Are you using the same xib for iPhone & iPad??

Comment: i use xcode 5 with storyboard and interface builder. i'm a beginner, so i don't know very well the xib but i have two storyboard one for iphone and one for ipad.

Comment: putt you code in view will appear and try!

Comment: RESOLVE with this method   [alertView performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(show) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:FALSE];

Comment: really i resolve with this method only in one view, in another view the problem still exist!

Comment: @BC_Dilum you re right, the first alert view gone dismiss after the second alert view, it's a problem of queue gdb. i don t know like execute the first dismiss before.